# Working nested for-loops into R code to reduce redundancy

Tags: r, for-loop

EDIT: The rasters were acquired from the National Weather Service (https://water.weather.gov/precip/download.php). My county shapefiles are for Kentucky and could be acquired from Esri's ArcGIS online data services.

I have 5 rasters that contain precipitation data for various periods of records: daily, previous 30 days, 60 days, 90 days, and 365 days. I want to perform zonal statistics to calculate the mean value of each raster that falls within a shapefile that represents a county boundary polygon. I have 120 county polygons.

I have code that works, but I'd like to refine it. Currently, it involves a lot of copying and pasting of the same code.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(maptools)

# County shapefiles
input_path <- "C:/path/to/shapefiles/GIS_data/Counties"
files <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$", full.names=TRUE)
allShapes <- lapply(files, readOGR)
filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$")

# Rasters
NWS1_daily <- raster(paste(daily_downloads, daily_fname, sep='/'), band = 1)
NWS1_prev30 <- raster(paste(bulk_downloads, prev30_fname, sep='/'), band = 1)
NWS1_prev90 <- raster(paste(bulk_downloads, prev90_fname, sep='/'), band = 1)
NWS1_prev120 <- raster(paste(bulk_downloads, prev120_fname, sep='/'), band = 1)
NWS1_prev365 <- raster(paste(bulk_downloads, prev365_fname, sep='/'), band = 1)

# Perform zonal statistics to acquire mean observation for each county
observations <- vector()
filenames <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(allShapes)){
  observations[i] <- c(extract(NWS1_daily, allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, weights=T, normalizeWeights=F))
  filenames<-files[i]
}
filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$") 
observations<-data.frame(observations,filenames,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

observations <- vector()
filenames <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(allShapes)){
  observations[i] <- c(extract(NWS1_prev30, allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, weights=T, normalizeWeights=F))
  filenames<-files[i]
}
filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$") 
observations<-data.frame(observations,filenames,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

observations <- vector()
filenames <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(allShapes)){
  observations[i] <- c(extract(NWS1_prev90, allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, weights=T, normalizeWeights=F))
  filenames<-files[i]
}
filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$") 
observations<-data.frame(observations,filenames,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

observations <- vector()
filenames <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(allShapes)){
  observations[i] <- c(extract(NWS1_prev120, allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, weights=T, normalizeWeights=F))
  filenames<-files[i]
}
filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$") 
observations<-data.frame(observations,filenames,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

observations <- vector()
filenames <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(allShapes)){
  observations[i] <- c(extract(NWS1_prev365, allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, weights=T, normalizeWeights=F))
  filenames<-files[i]
}
filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$") 
observations<-data.frame(observations,filenames,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

How would I go about placing a nested for loop into my existing code to tackle some of the redundancy?

I've been trying to do this using some online resources as a reference, but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
raster_names_band1 <- c(NWS1_daily, NWS1_prev30, NWS1_prev90, NWS1_prev120, NWS1_prev365)

# Perform zonal statistics on each county to acquire mean observation for each countt
observations <- vector()
raster_names_band1 <- vector()
filenames <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(allShapes))
  {
for (j in 1:length(raster_names_band1))
  observations[i] <- c(extract(raster_names_band1[[j]], allShapes[[i]], fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, weights=T, normalizeWeights=F))
  filenames<-files[i]
}
filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$") 
observations<-data.frame(observations,filenames,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## Error in raster_names_band1[[j]] : subscript out of bounds

## Error in data.frame(observations, filenames, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
## arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 120
```

I appreciate any advice you may have!

Comment: What package is `extract` from? In `tidyr` it breaks up columns but in `magrittr` it's just an alias for `[`.

Comment: Sorry - extract is from the raster package.

Comment: If you could figure out a way to have the example use publicly available data, so we could run the code, that would be a huge help.

Comment: Good thought. I updated the post with where the data could be acquired if folks want to use it.

Comment: Why do you repeat `filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$")`? And why build *filenames* in loop to its equivalent `list.files` call via *files* and then you end up re-assigning before `data.frame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [RasterLayers](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-7/topics/Raster-class) (the return of [`raster()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-7/topics/raster)) are special S4 class objects, binding them together with `c()` as in `c(NWS1_daily, NWS1_prev30, NWS1_prev90, NWS1_prev120, NWS1_prev365)` may not produce a list of five objects but possibly a simplified array of various dimensions. Inspect this object with `str(raster_names_band1)`. For complex objects, use `list()` to bind together in a collection.

Additionally, instead of nested `for` loops requiring bookkeeping of initializing objects and assigning to them, consider a nested apply family method. Specifically, run `lapply` to iterate across raster objects and nested `sapply` to iterate through *allShapes* to build *observations* for in `data.frame` call. Since *filenames* are the same for all, assign it once as a global object. Even wrap call with `setNames` to render a named list.

```
# LIST OF RASTER OBJECTS (USE list() NOT c())
raster_list <- list(NWS1_daily, NWS1_prev30, NWS1_prev90, NWS1_prev120, NWS1_prev365)
filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$"))

# USER-DEFINED FUNCTION
df_build <- function(obj_raster) {
   observations <- sapply(allShapes, function(s) 
                               c(extract(obj_raster, s, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, 
                                         weights=TRUE, normalizeWeights=FALSE))
                          )
   data.frame(observations, filenames, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
} 

# BUILD NAMED LIST OF DFs
df_list <- setNames(lapply(raster_list, df_build),
                    c("NWS1_daily", "NWS1_prev30", "NWS1_prev90", 
                      "NWS1_prev120", "NWS1_prev365")
                   )

# DF OUTPUTS
df_list$NWS1_daily
df_list$NWS1_prev30
df_list$NWS1_prev90
...
```

---

In fact, you can run nested `sapply` (wrapper to `lapply`) to avoid the `list` of raster objects and `setNames` but use a character vector of raster object names and `get()` to reference object by string:

```
raster_names <- c("NWS1_daily", "NWS1_prev30", "NWS1_prev90",
                  "NWS1_prev120", "NWS1_prev365")
filenames <- list.files(input_path, pattern="[.]shp$"))

df_build <- function(raster_nm) {
   # keep all same but change: extract(obj_raster, s, ... --> extract(get(raster_nm), s, ...
}

# BUILD NAMED LIST OF DFs
df_list <- sapply(raster_names, df_build, simplify = FALSE)
```

Note: above is untested code and may require various adjustments depending on global objects.